# QML How check is null or not?

Tags: qml

```
if(typeof(element) !== "undefined" && !element ){ // I tried this, but not work
    if(element.objectName === "right"){ // Get error in this line
     //....          
    }
}
```

Because of this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectName' of null`
, I need to check element is null or not. So any function like `isNull` available in qml?

Comment: Did you try `element !== undefined`?

Comment: @diiN_ tried, but not work

Comment: Are you sure, the <code>typeof(element)</code> can be undefined (is <code>var</code>)? Usually the latter 'if (!element)' should be sufficient, as long as element is not of type bool, but then the first will never evaluate to true.

Comment: Did you want to write `&& element` in that first if?

Comment: Can you output your `element`using the following function? `function testNull(object){ console.log("object:" + object, " ; typeof(object):" + typeof(object), " ; object!=undefined: " + (object!=undefined));}`

Comment: Thanks! @user2436719 object!==undefined is not work but object!=undefined is work. Output: qml: object:null  ; typeof(object):object  ; object!=undefined: false